# exchangelib and pyinstaller - zoneinfo - tzdata - UTC issue

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exchangelib, zoneinfo, tzdata

In my python project, I'm using exchangelib and I needed to create an exe file.
Using pyinstaller --onefile I had UTC errors (in general tzdata)-
"No timzone in key UTC".
Simplifying all and following this issue
https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/897
I noticed that the issue was the same with this simple code:

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
utc = ZoneInfo('UTC')
```

I also tried with py2exe, cx_freeze, forcing tzdata import, same issue.

I spent a lot of time finding a workaround and I want to share my temporary solution but also discuss other alternative solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me after exploring different options:

> pyinstaller --collect-all tzdata --onefile file_name.py

PS: I have been facing this problem and reached here to explore about pyinstaller. Your solution works too but its a directory where as I wanted it to be exe.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The workaround proposing copying the `tzdata` folder is much clunkier than this.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I found is to use pyinstaller --onedir (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) and manually copy tzdata folder (\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\tzdata) in the main dir created by pyinstaller.
Do you have more elegant other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I used the spec file for packaging, and packaged the resource files in the configuration.

binaries=[('C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tzdata\zoneinfo\UTC','tzdata\zoneinfo')]
pathex=['C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tzdata\zoneinfo']
hiddenimports=['tzdata.zoneinfo']

Comment: @Fabio Fracassi

Comment: I updated my original answer with more details.